# Hairdresser terminology and Russian equivalents

Tags: перевод, значения, терминология

Friends, help me out please. I'm doing a translation and can't find the best and most-correct Russian equivalents for a few terms:

- Layered hairstyle
- Choppy hairstyle
- Hair band
- Hair accessories
- Funky look
- Messy look
- Messy hair
- Crop hair
- Rough look
- To carry a haircut
- To carry a bang on one side or both sides of the head
- Side swept bang
- Straitened hair
- Trendy look
- To adopt a side-bang to a hairstyle
- Hairstyle texture
- Tones of blond
- Razor-cut hairstyles.
- Hairstyle up-do
- New hairstyle styles and features.
- Cranky look

And I can't understand the difference between **"bang"** and **"bangs"**. it seems that in Russian it's all **"чёлка"**. But in English they say for instance: **a hairstyle with a side-bang** or **a haircut with short bangs**.

Difference between a **'light blond tone'** and **'light shade of blond'**?

Comment: @V.V. Funky - эксцентричный?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Hair band

Soft band that you can use to tie long hair into ponytail is "резинка для волос". Google Picture also shows hard bow-shaped thing which can be put vertically around your head. This thing is "ободок".

> Messy hair

A person having messy hair is "лохматый"/"лохматая" (adj.). "лохматые волосы" also work. Also does (but worse) "лохматая причёска". 
A literal translation is "лохмы" but it is much rarely used than "лохматый" and sounds more negative ("лохмы" can never be stylish, while "лохматые волосы" can be).

> Crop hair

Less formally it's "причёска/стрижка под мальчика". For hairdressers it's probably "гарсон".

> To carry a haircut

Literal "носить стрижку" works here pretty good. "у него/у меня/ у неё <some characteristic> стрижка" also works.

> Straitened hair

Выпрямленные волосы.

> Hairstyle up-do

Высокая причёска

Regarding these ones I am less confident:

> Layered hairstyle

Google says this hairstyle is known as "каскад" in Russian but you better recheck it.

> Hair accessories

"Аксессуары для волос" look fine for me. Also it feels like someone can find something better.

> Hairstyle texture

"Текстура причёски" sounds fine for me. Although there maybe more professional translation.

Comment: Oops, didn't see that you are Russian, so all this information is probably obvious to you.

Comment: A few more terms and i'll be really thankful.

Answer (score 3):

Layered hairstyle - "слои", in professional terminology. For the clients you can say "текстурированная стрижка", the same as choppy hairstyle - "подвижная текстура волос".

- Funky look - молодёжный/ стильный/ эксцентричный/
  утрированный стиль одежды.
- Messy look, messy hair - прибрежный стиль.
- Crop hair - на висках и затылке градация с нуля и слои в теменной зоне, in professional terminology. "Стрижка под мальчика" in very simple words.
- Rough look - очень мужественный вид.
- To carry a haircut - носить стрижку.
- To carry a bang on one... - носить чёлку на одну или обе стороны.
- Sideswept bang - универсальная чёлка/ чёлка на обе стороны.
- Trandy look - модный образ.
- To adopt a side bang... - вписать чёлку в прическу/ адаптировать боковую чёлку к прическе.
- Tones of blond - оттенки/цвета блонда, literally blond translates as светлый, but we (both hairdressers and client) don't use this word, we use blond=блонд, блондинка - girl with light hair.
- Razor cut hairstyles - Стрижка бритвой.
- Up do - высокая прическа.
- New hairstyle styles - новые тенденции в стрижка, features - элементы in haircuts.

Comment: Formatting it in a list would be much better. If you don't know how to do it, tell us, someone will edit your answer. Oh, and welcome to Russian.SX!

Comment: "Messy look, messy hair - прибрежный стиль" - вы имели в виду "небрежный"?